# Positioning text with the :after pseudo selector

Tags: css

I have this:

```
    div#myImg{
        background: url('myimage.png') left top no-repeat;
    }

    div#myImg:after{
        content: 'TEXT UNDER IMAGE';
        margin:0 auto;
        vertical-align:text-bottom;
        font-size: 14px;
    }           

    .dm_lp_imgs{
        width: 100px;
        float:left;
        height: 115px;
        margin-right: 15px;
    } 


    <div id="myImg" class="lp_imgs"></div>
```

I know you can add text with the :after pseudo selector, but I want to position that text, centered, just below my image.
Can I do that with the :after pseudo selector?

At the moment, the text seems stuck to the top of the div#myImg DIV.

UPDATE:

```
display:block
```

Doesn't do the trick...

Comment: If the 'text' is intended to be **actual content** then it should not be used in the `content` property in a pseudo element.

Comment: Sorry @AmitJoki, I posted this just as I left the office, didn't have time to throw up a jsfiddle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually I use CSS `position` to do that sort of thing.  Make the parent `position:relative`, add `position:absolute` to the `::after` element, and give it a `top:100%`

http://jsfiddle.net/s22Af/

```
div#myImg:after{
    content: 'TEXT UNDER IMAGE';
    margin:0 auto;
    vertical-align:text-bottom;
    font-size: 14px;

    position:absolute;
    top: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}           

.dm_lp_imgs{
    width: 100px;
    float:left;
    height: 115px;
    margin-right: 15px;

    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can position pseudo elements absolutely relative to the parent. Add `position: relative` to the `div` and `position: absolute` to the `:after` CSS, then position using usual methods. I've done a quick fiddle of it here: http://jsfiddle.net/5s3Fr/

Answer (score 2):

I don't know your requirements but if you're coding for modern browsers/html5 you should look into the `<figure>` and `<figcaption>` html tags

For your consideration:  [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Wc2Tf/)

**Markup:**

```
<figure id="myFigure">
    <div id="myImg" class="dm_lp_imgs"></div>
    <figcaption>text under image</figcaption>
</figure>
```

**CSS**

```css
.dm_lp_imgs {
    width: 100px;
    height: 115px;
}

#myFigure {
    float:left;
    margin-right: 15px;
    width: 100px;
}

#myImg { background: url('myimage.png') left top no-repeat; }

#myImg + figcaption {
    /* Style caption here */
    text-align:center;
    text-transform:capitalize;
}
```

Comment: This is a question involving CSS styling.  It has nothing to do with semantic html5

Comment: correct, which means the OP may not be asking the right question.  Just putting another option out there

Comment: Regardless, if the OP decides to try this and finds that this doesn't change anything (because the default styles for these elements are just block level with some margin added), it will not help him.  This answer is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: You make my point.  The question is trying to solve a problem for which the authors of the HTML5 spec deemed worthy to have specific tags for the express purpose that the OP is trying to finagle with pseudo elements.  To me this seemed an XY issue, hence my post.